# Local linear approximation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have some `x` and `y` data, where for every entry in the `x` vector there's a corresponding entry in the `y` vector. Furthermore, the `x` data are not evenly spaced.

I'd like to interpolate between the `x` samples to obtain an even spacing in the `x` dimension, and to approximate the corresponding `y` value. In **numpy**, `interp1d` seems like a natural solution, but my problem has a caveat: the `x` values are not monotonically increasing (because both `x` and `y` are a function of time). The `interp1d` function, and the other functions from the interpolate module, thus give weird results at those points where `x` reverses direction.

What I'd really like to do is simply fit a straight line between every set of two adjacent `x` points and then interpolate based on this very local approximation. Is there a function to do this in **numpy** or do I have to rig something up myself?

Comment: You should remember to mark helpful answers as "accepted"; this helps other people looking at your question to find the most useful answer, and also gives recognition to those you take the time to help you out.

Comment: If `x` doesn't increase or decrease monotonically, you don't have a unique mapping.  For example, if you have `x=array([0, 1, 0])`, which two points should be interpolated if you pass `xx = 0.5`?

Comment: I understand there's no unique mapping. But, assuming x = array([0,1,0]) if I gave the interpolated input as xx=array([0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0]), then what I'd like to get back for the first 0.5 value is the halfway point between the first 2 ys and for the second 0.5 value the halfway point between the second two ys, if that explanation makes sense.

Comment: Do you have access to the time variable? If so, you can use multivariate regression to predict y based on both x and t.

Comment: multivariate regression sounds reasonable, except then I'd need to figure out how fast y is changing as a function of x, which basically reduces to rigging something on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Could you sort your xy pairs and then use interp1d?  Something like this?

```
import sort
xy = zip(x,y)
new_xy = sorted(xy, key=lambda xy: xy[0])
x = new_xy[:,0]
y = new_xy[:,1]
```

Now your x's are monotonically increasing and the relationships have been preserved.